# Sending email from a web application on .NET 4.5 IIS7 works OK on test but not on live server

Tags: .net, iis-7, .net-4.5

I have just "upgraded" a web site from a Windows 2003 server with IIS6 built to .NET 3.5 to a Windows 2012 server with IIS7 re-built to .NET 4.5.

The code is unchanged. It uses `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage` and connects to a remote server to send via that server's SMTP. Because it sends to a remote server the local SMTP service is irrelevant as are the firewalls of both machines (I tried it with both firewalls disabled).

The problem is that the web application no longer send emails. When the page that sends the email is submitted it takes a couple of minutes to postback (before it was more or less instantaneous) and the `MailMessage.Send()` method does not return an error. It is as if the email has been sent, albeit slowly, but it hasn't because it never arrives.

I suspect either the IIS7 setup or differences between .NET 3.5 and 4.5.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can your server be blacklisted? Did you activate SMTP roles in your server? What is the "remote server"? Did you look at Windows Events?

Comment: Thanks for response. Not blacklisted, SMTP service running, can't see anything in the events logs. The remote server is one I have complete control of and it all worked fine from the old hosting server running Windows server 2003 and IIS6, when the web forms app was built to .NET 3.5.

Comment: Ah :( but what is your remote server? is it a server you created as a SMTP server or is it a third party (e.g. smtp.google.com). Can you show us your smtp/port. If you used to use IIS 6 smtp server there has been some changes in IIS 7.5

Comment: It's a remote dedicated mail server running MailEnable on Windows server 2003. That is running fine. The problem is with the web hosting server (windows 2012, IIS7 which is sending the mail to that remote server using System.Net.Mail.MailMessage (.NET 4.5).

Comment: The new server had port 25 blocked by the the hosting company Redstation. This is an unmanaged dedicated server, the old server I was moving the sites from was also an unmanaged dedicated Redstation server which didn't have the port restriction. Not happy with and wouldn't recommend Redstation.